# Should I design a class to handle my other class or the attribute of my other class?

Tags: python, class-design

Please allow me to illustrate my question with a simple example. Let's suppose we have a Customer class:

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, email):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email
```

And we also have a Bill class that needs info from a Customer object instance. Should I write the Bill by providing a Customer object instance as an argument?

```
class Bill:

    def __init__(self, amount, customer):
        self.amount = amount
        self.customer = customer
   
    def to_txt(self):
        with open("bill.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"{self.customer.name} due amount is {self.amount}")

customer = Customer("John", "Smith", "john@gmail.com")
bill = Bill(100, customer)
```

Or should Bill simply get a name as an argument as shown below?

```
class Bill:

    def __init__(self, amount, period, customer):
        self.amount = amount
        self.period = period
        self.customer_name = customer_name
   
    def to_txt(self):
        with open("bill.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"{self.customer_name} due amount is {self.amount}")

    customer = Customer("John", "Smith", "john@gmail.com")
    bill = Bill(100, customer.name)
```

Edit: A user dubbed [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325743/object-oriented-python-methods-and-their-parameters) as a duplicate, but that question is about passing attributes between different methods in the same class. My question is about passing attributes between different classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object Oriented Python methods and their parameters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325743/object-oriented-python-methods-and-their-parameters)

Comment: @gnat, no. That is about attributes among the methods of the same class. My question is about attributes among different classes.

Comment: Should be https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209218/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-using-objects-as-parameters-to-other-ob

Comment: @jonrsharpe that answered my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the advantages/disadvantages of using objects as parameters to other object methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209218/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-using-objects-as-parameters-to-other-ob)

Answer (score 0):

Calling self.customer.name and bypassing the objects interface is the same as passing the name into the constructor.

If you properly encapsulated the customer object and passed it to the Bill would be the best solution since you would be programming to their interfaces.

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, email):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email

    def getName():
        return self.name    


class Bill:

    def __init__(self, amount, customer):
        self.amount = amount
        self.customer = customer
   
    def to_txt(self):
        with open("bill.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"{self.customer.getName()} due amount is {self.amount}")





customer = Customer("John", "Smith", "john@gmail.com")
bill = Bill(100, customer)
```